# Generating ToastNotifications from Python

Tags: python, windows, notifications, toast

I want to implement a plugin for [gajim](http://www.gajim.org) to have native notifications on Windows 8/10 via [Toasts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.aspx). Are there any implementations for toasting notifications from python code? At the moment I am calling a powershell script, but that does not feel right.